# WARN: SQL(org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions) Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernateexception

Getting `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions` when I am trying to delete a record in hibernate using `session.delete(cust)`
Please provide some help. Thanks!
I have tried to check the field mapping for id column.
And before calling delete method, id is bound with the `cust` object.

```
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
  SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  long id = 2;
  try {
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    Customer cust = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, id);
    session.delete(cust);
    t.commit();
  } catch (HibernateException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message? This looks like a query syntax error so there should be a message explaining what part of the query is incorrect

Comment: WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where CUSTOMER_ID=2' at line 1 org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapmapManagedFlushFailure ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete CUSTOMER_MASTER2 where CUSTOMER_ID=?]]

Comment: Have you checked if you set up hibernate properly for the right version of language/dialect the databse uses?

Comment: Can you please post your mapping and your table structure? My guess is that there's an error between the table/column names in the mapping